# Difference in meaning: たくない vs なくたい

Tags: meaning

Is there a difference in meaning between たくない　and なくたい?
For example:

- 忘れたくない
- 忘れなくたい

Intended meaning:
"I don't want to forget"

Comment: なくたい is not a real form.  Sure it wasn't ネクタイ?

Comment: Do you mean 忘れなくしたい?

Comment: 忘れなくたい is simply ungrammatical. It means nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

忘れたくない is correct, because...

The auxiliary たい can attach to verbs, like this:

忘れ+たい
飲み+たい
座り+たい

and ない can attach to auxiliaries as well as verbs, like this:

忘れ+ない
飲ま+ない
座ら+ない
忘れたく+ない
食べたく+ない
忘れられ+ない
食べさせ+ない

On the other hand 忘れなくたい is ungrammatical because たい can only attach to verbs and **auxiliaries (ら)れる and (さ)せる**:

◎認められ+たい
◎食べさせ+たい
×忘れなく+たい ← incorrect
×食べなく+たい ← incorrect

---

For reference, 明鏡国語辞典 says:

> たい 〘助動　形型〙
> 《動詞および助動詞「（さ）せる」、助動詞「（ら）れる」の連用形に付いて》希望を表す。